# How do I validate a recaptcha in node without a challenge field?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, recaptcha

The latest version of recaptcha no longer expects a challenge field, the angular-recaptcha directive is up to date with these changes, but none of the node recaptcha libraries work without a challenge field.

How do I validate a recaptcha in node without a challenge field?

Answer (score 0):

```
    function verifyRecaptcha(key, callback) {
        https.get("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" + recaptcha_vars.privateKey + "&response="         + key, function(res) {
            var data = "";
            res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                            data += chunk.toString();
            });
            res.on('end', function() {
                try {
                    var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log(parsedData);
                    callback(parsedData.success);
                } catch (e) {
                    callback(false);
                }
            });
        });
    }



    exports.captcha = function(req, res) {


            verifyRecaptcha(req.body.response, function(success) {
                    if (success) {
                            res.json({ success: true });

                            // TODO: do registration using params in req.body
                    } else {
                            res.json({ success: success, error: "Captcha failed"});
                            // TODO: take them back to the previous page
                            // and for the love of everyone, restore their inputs
                    }
            });

    };
```